# C# Trying to make a calculator code which would loop results to other columns of textboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a calculator which would fill 3 x 4 table of Textboxes. Each of the three rows would calculated using a different variables. This would be done 4 times.

The textboxes in the form are:

textBox11, textBox21, textBox31, textBox41
textBox12, textBox22, textBox32, textBox42
textBox13, textBox23, textBox33, textBox43

I can fill what is essentialy a single column.

This works:

```
double var1 = Convert.ToDouble(tb_value1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double var2 = Convert.ToDouble(tb_value2.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double var3 = Convert.ToDouble(tb_value3.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

int WP = 1;

var S1 = Math.Pow((var2 - var1) * WP, 2);
var S2 = Math.Pow(4 + var3, 2);
var S3 = Math.Pow(var1, 2);
 
var Calc1 = (S1 * (var2 / 3));
var Calc2 = (S1 * S3) / WP;
var Calc3 = var3 + var1 * (S2 / WP);

textBox11.Text = Calc1.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
textBox12.Text = Calc2.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
textBox13.Text = Calc3.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
```

The code successfully calculates a column of three different results.

`WP` is used in the variables `S1` - `S3` and `Calc1` - `Calc3`.

The question is how could i get this to work in a `for` loop where the `WP` is the loop's variable.

Something like this

```
double var1 = Convert.ToDouble(tb_value1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double var2 = Convert.ToDouble(tb_value2.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double var3 = Convert.ToDouble(tb_value3.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

for ( WP = 1; WP <= 4; WP++)
                {
                    var S1 = Math.Pow((var2 - var1) * WP, 2);
                    var S2 = Math.Pow(4 + var3, 2);
                    var S3 = Math.Pow(var1, 2);
 
                    var Calc1 = (S1 * (var2 / 3));
                    var Calc2 = (S1 * S3) / WP;
                    var Calc3 = var3 + var1 * (S2 / WP);

                    textBox11.Text = Calc1.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
                    textBox12.Text = Calc2.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
                    textBox13.Text = Calc3.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
                }
```

Using that `for` loop it is supposed to loop 4 times giving three (3) results for each of the four (4) columns.

The Problem is that i'm not sure how to do this in the most efficient way possible.

My first attempt was trying to have the first number after "textBox" as a variable like:

```
String.Format("textBox{0}1", WP)
```

But it is most likely I did something wrong.

Comment: Since you have some form of grid there, then use a real grid, as a DataGridView, to present your data. After that, loop the Rows of the grid. Or, better, use a collection of objects that describe the data per row and set this collections as the DataSource of the DataGridView, so each time you update the data, this is automatically reflected in the grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, you need to turn your individual `TextBox` variables into an array or arrays that you can index.

```
TextBox[][] textBoxOutputGroups = new[]
{
    new [] { textBox11, textBox12, textBox13, },
    new [] { textBox21, textBox22, textBox23, },
    new [] { textBox31, textBox32, textBox33, },
    new [] { textBox41, textBox42, textBox43, },
};
```

Now you can rewrite your code to output the results into the correct row/column of your grid:

```
double var1 = Convert.ToDouble(tb_value1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double var2 = Convert.ToDouble(tb_value2.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double var3 = Convert.ToDouble(tb_value3.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

for (int WP = 1; WP <= 4; WP++)
{
    var S1 = Math.Pow((var2 - var1) * WP, 2);
    var S2 = Math.Pow(4 + var3, 2);
    var S3 = Math.Pow(var1, 2);

    double[] outputValues = new[]
    {
        S1 * var2 / 3,
        S1 * S3 / WP,
        var3 + var1 * S2 / WP,
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < outputValues.Length; i++)
    {
        textBoxOutputGroups[WP - 1][i].Text =
            outputValues[i].ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
    }
}
```

Your formulas didn't require making arrays of your inputs or calculations.

Comment: What do you mean "It doesn't work"? I ran it on VS 2022, It does work. If you refering to variables S1-S3 and Calc1-Calc3 that is intentional. The equations that are supposed to occupy those spots are something I have no authority to reveal.

Comment: @kurmi - When I copy and paste the code you said works from your question it doesn't compile. So it doesn't work. It's not code that I can use to construct an answer. I had to rewrite it. Had you post compilable and runnable code then I could have answered you more directly.

Comment: @kurmi - If you couldn't reveal the actual functions then make up something you can reveal so that you are posting working code.

Comment: Alright, I have now provided some equations hope that helps.

Comment: @kurmi - It's getting better. The issue I have now is that I cannot see how `WP` makes a difference. You have three fixed input values. The forumulas are all independent of `WP` and you're setting the three textboxes in your grid.

Comment: You were correct i did forget the WP from my formulas. That has now been fixed.